# Prove that no 5 digit EXTREME PRIMES exist.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

I have been trying to come up with my own math problems recently and this is one of my first. It introduces the idea of an extreme prime. I hope that an extreme prime isn't already a thing, because I just used the name to describe a special number. I have a solution to the problem, but I'd like to see smarter solutions and get some feedback on the problem so I can make better ones in the future.

An extreme prime is a number such that every number within the number is prime, expect one-digit numbers, and the number itself is prime. Examples are below for clarity, as I'm bad at explaining.

Examples:

- $617$ is a prime. Also, $61$ is a prime and $17$ is a prime. Therefore $617$ is an extreme prime. Note $6$ is composite: the digits need not be prime.
- $1373$ is prime. Also, $13$ is prime, $37$ is prime, $73$ is prime, $137$ is prime, $373$ is prime. Therefore $1317$ is an extreme prime. Fun fact: $373$ is also the only $3$ digits extreme prime where the digits are prime, so I guess it must be ultra-prime.

The question is to prove that no $5$ digit extreme prime exists. I'm looking forward to some feedback and some ways I can word what an extreme prime is, hope it is fun to solve.

Some other facts I noticed when checking my proof with python (which I do not have a proof for):
you may like to try to prove them.

- A $3$ digit extreme prime cannot contain a $2,8$ or $5$.
- A $4$ digit extreme prime cannot contain a $2, 8, 5$ or $4$.
- A $4$ digit extreme prime never starts with $7$.

Quite a few super primes (primes that occupy prime numbered positions in the sequence of all prime numbers) are extreme primes. Can you find them all and create the prime-st number set of all time!

Comment: This sounds closely related to "truncatable" primes. See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TruncatablePrime.html for example.

Comment: Also:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3363782/primes-within-primes-primeception

Comment: People are referring to truncutable primes. They are not the same. Such number from the question would need to be right truncutable, left tructutable, and have primes in the middle of the digits. Not sure why these questions are related? If the proofs are mathematically similar I would understand, is this the case?

Comment: @ScuffedNewton, you're quite right that your "extreme" primes are not literally the same as "truncatable" primes, but they are a *subset* of the intersection of the left- and right-truncatable primes, and given that those sets are both finite, so is the set of extreme primes.

Comment: I should add, it might be possible to prove the result you're after without making use of what's known about truncatable primes. So I don't mean to suggest that your notion of "extreme" prime is not worth pursuing. It's a nice idea, in fact. Kudos for thinking of it.

Comment: With backtracking, we can probably find all such primes. I do not think that the number of such primes exceeds $10$ a lot, if this is reached at all.

Comment: @ Barry Cipra, that link you attached says there is a limited amount of right/left truncutable primes. Also They are not necessarily intersections as the digits need not be prime, hence the first and last digits can be composite,but must be prime if they are to be truncutable. Another thing is that if we take the number 1373, no trunctuable condition requires 37 to be prime, but the extreme prime does. While some terms are the same, the extreme primes include and exclude some other terms due to the above points.

Comment: @ Barry Cipra, so for example, 1373 is right trunctable but not left, but is extreme. 373 is right truncutable, left trunctuable, and extreme.  Some numbers can be left and right truncutable but not extreme.

Comment: @ScuffedNewton, good point. I stand corrected. Sorry, I should have compared the definitions more closely.

Comment: @Peter, there are quite a few, I know there are no 5 digits, the proof lends itself to say 4 is the max. All 2 digit primes are extreme according to the definition, and one digit primes can't be extreme. Here are all the 3 and 4 digits: 113
131
137
173
179
197
311
313
317
373
379
419
431
479
613
617
619
673
719
797
971, 1373, 3137, 3797, 6131, 6173, 6197, 9719

Comment: @ScuffedNewton 1373 **IS** left-truncatable. I assume that you meant 1373 is not **RIGHT**-truncatable because 1 obviously isn't

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $p=d_1d_2\ldots d_n$ be an $n$-digit prime with digits $d_i$.  We can define an "extreme" prime recursively as follows: If $n=2$, then $p$ is an extreme prime; if $n\gt2$ then $p$ is extreme if and only if the truncations $d_1d_2\ldots d_{n-1}$ and $d_2\ldots d_n$ are both extreme primes.

It's not hard to see that there only ten $2$-digit primes that can occur in the interior of an $n$-digit extreme prime (with $n\ge4$, so that there is a proper "interior"):

$$11,13,17,19,31,37,71,73,79,97$$

Each of these can be extended on either side to give a $3$-digit extreme prime, but only six of them can be extended on both sides to give a $4$-digit extreme prime. As the OP reports, the $4$-digit extreme primes are

$$1373,3137,3797,6131,6197,9719$$

The only possible extension to a $5$-digit number whose truncations back to four digits both belong to this list is $31373$. (For example, $3797$ cannot be extended on the left because none of the $4$-digit extreme primes are of the form $d_1379$, and it cannot be extended on the right because none of the $4$-digit extreme primes are of the form $797d_4$.) But $31373=137\cdot229$ is not a prime. So there are no $5$-digit extreme primes (hence no extreme primes with more than $5$ digits as well).

Remark: The hardest part of this proof is the part that the OP did, namely identifying the six $4$-digit extreme primes. I don't see any easy way to get to those six without a tedious case-by-case analysis. If anyone can think of a nice way to streamline things, I'd be keen to see it.